# Xaml visibility binding in Windows Phone?

Tags: xaml

I'm using a LongListSelector and I will like to bind the visibility of the ListHeader to the count of the items. If there aren't any than collapsed it else make it visible.

How can I achieved this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a valueconverter to get this => implement the IValueconverter interface.

if there are no items return enum collapsed, otherwise visible.

Bind the Count of the items to the collapsed dependency property using the converter.

see msdn for more info => http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx